# PHP find string in array

Tags: php, explode

I have a column profile in MySql

```
firstset=one;two;three|secondset=blue;yellow;red;|thirdset=width;height;|
```

(expample) I need to get: `yellow` from `secondset` to variable

What i wrote:

```
... MySql query etc ...
...
if ($r_select['profile'] != null)
{       
    $resultSelect = $r_select['profile']; 

    $resultArray = explode('|', $resultSelect);
```

So now i have:

```
resultArray (

[1] firstset=one;two;three
[2] secondset=blue;yellow;red;
[3] thirdset=width;height;

)
```

I need to find where in `resultArray[]` is `secondset=` then save this in variable- i want to get

```
 $found = "secondset=blue;yellow;red;"
```

I know how to `explode` variable but i cant find string in array[]

Comment: Doesn't `in_array()` do what you want to find a string in an array?

Comment: Things would be so much easier if you normalized your database instead of storing everything in one column.

Comment: his  both comments are correct

Comment: Loop through `$resultArray`. Split the element first on `=`, then split the second part of that on `;`. Then use `in_array()` to search that array for `"yellow"`.

Comment: Barmar- First: i can create new table in database only with profie but there will be about 40 kolumns. It is still ok ? just asking. Second:  but if `yellow` will be in `firstset` too ?
So what will be better? create new table or playing around with it?

Comment: @Kafus  your selected answer will not work in the case:- `resultArray ( [1] firstset=one;two;three [2] secondset=blue;yellow;red; [3] thirdset=width;height; [4] thirdset=width;height;yellow; )` 4th one skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($r_select['profile'] != null) {

    $resultSelect = $r_select['profile']; 
    $resultArray  = explode('|', $resultSelect); 

    foreach ($resultArray as $data) {

        if (strpos($data, 'secondset') !== FALSE) {
            $found = $data;
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $found;
```

Result:

```
secondset=blue;yellow;red;
```

Comment: because of `break` don't you think if next indexes also have `yellow` that will ignored?

Comment: @kafus  if your array have more than one time same value then only first one will come and others will skip. Check once.  for  example:-  `resultArray (

[1] firstset=one;two;three
[2] secondset=blue;yellow;red;
[3] thirdset=width;height;
[4] thirdset=width;height;yellow;
)`

Comment: yes but first of all i'll get variable with `secondset=blue;yellow;red;` then i can look for my `'yellow'`. There is no option that i can get 2x `secondset`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this.

```
$result = Array (

'1' =>'firstset=one;two;three',
'2' =>'secondset=blue;yellow;red;',
'3' =>'thirdset=width;height;'

);
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    if(strpos($value,'yellow')){
        $secondset = $value;
        break;

    }

}

$result1 = explode('=', $secondset);
$result2 = explode(';', $result1[1]);
list($a,$b,$c) = $result2;
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without foreach:

```
$resultArray =  [
    'firstset=one;two;three',
    'secondset=blue;yellow;red;',
    'thirdset=width;height;',
];

// all the results matching secondset
$result = preg_grep('/.*secondset.*/', $resultArray);
// if you have only one result
$resultString = reset($result);
```

Then you can apply your explode on $resultString. If you have several results, like many string in your array with "secondset" on it, you will be able to process them in the array $result.

```
$result -> array(1) {
  [1] =>
  string(26) "secondset=blue;yellow;red;"
}

$resultString -> string(26) "secondset=blue;yellow;red;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function with custom anonymous function.

```
$resultArray  = array("firstset=one;two;three", "secondset=blue;yellow;red;", "thirdset=width;height;");  

$matches = array_filter($resultArray, function ($haystack) {
    return strpos($haystack, 'secondset=') !== false ? true : false;
});

   // output => Array ( [1] => secondset=blue;yellow;red; )
print_r($matches);
```

To obtain all array keys (in your case only one):

```
// output => Array ( [0] => 1 )
print_r(array_keys($matches));
```